# Удаленное подключение к Mysql из PHP Azure WebSite

Tags: azure, azure-websites

Добрый день!

Возник такой вопрос. Есть сайт на Azure Websites. И есть виртуальная машина на которой развернут Ubuntu + MySQL. По DNS имени я конекчусь к MySQL без каких либо проблме. Порт 3306 открыт на машине Ubuntu, конечные точки для 3306 настроены.

Но при попытке подключиться из PHP сайта на Azure получаю такую ошибку:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Вот мой web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1h" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)\?*$"  />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может сокет уже занят каким нибудь процессом? Попробуй из убунты исполнить netstat -o, может покажет чем забит. Или может с кодом что-то не то? Запости как ты получаешь доступ к MySQL. Ошибка выходит когда запускаешь с локальной машины или именно из Azure-Websites?

Comment: Самое интересное что я без каких либо проблем подключаюсь по этим же реквизитам с локального сайта и даже с навиката

Comment: И всё же мой вопрос был не отвечен. Ошибка выходит когда запускаешь с локальной машины или именно из Azure-Websites?

Comment: Именно с Azure Websites

Comment: А Connection String в Azure настроен? Как тут указанно: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ или тут http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/